# Reparent child records from different child objects

Tags: batch, lookup, update

I have a situation where I have a parent object with around 15 lookup child objects.
In a certain business scenario, the parent record will be replaced by another parent record, so that all these lookups on all these associated child objects need to be reparented to the other parent record.

The exact number of child object records per child object type is unknown but the total number of all the child records for a single parent can be more than 10000.
What could be the best way to process this reparenting?

Considering the row count, it seems asynchronous is the way to go, however thinking of a batch, I am unsure as: it is not rows from a single object to be modified, rather 15 different objects.

Looking at the return type of the Batchable start method, it appears that we are restricted to one type of object only in a single batch.
I looked into the other flavour, i.e. using Iterable, though that too doesn't help much.
The only other option seems to be to spawn a separate batch for every different child object type, and chain then using Queueable, which gives me about 15 different batches.

But I am completely unsure if that is a good approach, or whether there are any other options. Any pointers will be appreciated, thanks!